# How to find my existing Apple ID based on my Email Account

Tags: apple-id

I have a Gmail account and an Apple ID associated with this account.

When I go to create a new account with the same email address, I am unable to.

How can I retrieve this *APPLE ID* associated with this e-mail address?

Comment: Usually the Apple ID is the email itself. So if the Gmail account is `myAccount@gmail.com`, the Apple ID would be `myAccount@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

To get it directly, go to this page: https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid

In the future, if you don't remember where that page is, you can also get to it from the Apple ID Site

1. Go to [Apple ID](http://appleid.apple.com/)
2. Click "Find your Apple ID." at the bottom of the page
3. You will need to fill out some info including your name and the email address.

For screenshots, See this page:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5625?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: the `iforgot` link gives erroneous information.